# Visual studio 2017 add extension to real top bar

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

How do I add my extension to the "real" VS? Currently I have followed this guide

[VS 2017 Extension guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-a-menu-to-the-visual-studio-menu-bar?view=vs-2017)

The guide only shows you how to add the extension to the top menu when running VS in an "experimental instance". How can I add the extension to not only the experimental instance but also the normal VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "experimental instance" is for debug mode.

> For your local vs extension:

To add extension to `real vs`, double click the extensionName.vsix file and the extension will be added to your VS automatically.(Your vs producct should meet the extension's prerequisites)

PS: You can find the xx.vsix in `ProjectDir/bin/Debug or Release` folder.

> If you publish your extension to [VS
>   Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/):

We can find this extension within vs by go Tools menu=>Extensions and Updates=>Online to find it using search window, and click download to install it.